# How to select and layout the contents of <details> without selecting <summary> using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I'm trying to add 10px padding to the Story box using CSS, *without* adding any new extra HTML elements to the website code.

Is there any way to add the padding to the Story box, without adding a new extra HTML element?

In other words:
How to select ONLY the Story box using only CSS, without selecting the `<summary>` part with it? (I like the current layout of the `<summary>` I don't want to change anything there.)

```css
details {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid black
}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  user-select: none
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Our Next Holiday Options</summary>


  Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story tory Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story ory Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story ry Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story y Story Story Story Story Story Story Story
  Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story


</details>
```

Comment: CSS selects elements, not “boxes”. But I am not sure where the actual problem is supposed to lie here - apply the 10px padding you currently have for `summary`, to `details` _instead_ …?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply padding to the whole element and you consider negative margin on summary to disable it.

Example with 20px so we can better see:

```css
details {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px; /* the padding here */
  outline: 1px solid black
}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:-20px; /* negative margin here */
  user-select: none
}
details[open] summary {
  margin-bottom:20px; /* the bottom the same as padding*/
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Our Next Holiday Options</summary>


  Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story tory Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story ory Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story ry Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story y Story Story Story Story Story Story Story
  Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story


</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the summary element the details element has an attribute added - "open". You can use css to target attributes using square brackets - `[open]`. I have added css to add padding to the details element while removing it from summary when the attribute is present.

```css
details {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: 1px solid black
}

summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  user-select: none
}

details[open] {
  padding: 10px;
}

details[open] summary {
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Our Next Holiday Options</summary>


  Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story tory Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story ory Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story ry Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story y Story Story Story Story Story Story Story
  Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story Story


</details>
```